# Windows 7: System date and time resets to 2007

Tags: windows-7, date-time

My desktop computer has been upgraded to Windows 7 and ever since whenever I start it up, it resets the date and time to 2007. I tried changing the battery on the motherboard thinking that it would solve, but its still the same.

I didn't face this trouble when Windows XP was installed on this computer. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you boot into the BIOS and see if it is reporting the same date and time?

Comment: Yes the BIOS reports the same time

Comment: I'm assuming by "same time" we mean the time that Windows is displaying (the 2007 one). This would suggest that it isn't Windows' fault. But, since you said you replaced the BIOS battery, I'm at a loss. Do any changes you make to the BIOS stick around after a shutdown?

Comment: Yes they do, this is one insane problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tell your computer to sync to an internet time server.  It's in the clock options, under a tab called "Internet Time", I believe.  I'd give more details (even a screenshot, probably) if I weren't stuck right now in a fresh install of Linux. :)

Comment: but what happens if I go offline ? My ISP is quite irritating sometimes and I need repeated efforts in order to sign into my account.

Comment: Internet time synchronization does not require a constant connection.  The service will attempt to synchronize at start-up and periodically thereafter.  If you observe that after syncing your clock, it still falls back to 2007 *while your computer is running*, there is probably a nefarious program somewhere on your system.  Anyway, methinks it's at least worth a shot.

Comment: my system was already synced and it does sometime keep to the actually time, then some days it acts all loney and decides to go back to 2007, freaky little thing

Answer (score 0):

just [change](http://www.trendinginfo.net) the BIOS battery, it will work fine. it worked for me me.

Comment: "I tried changing the battery on the motherboard" - He did

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.